# MSDN sample and missing SDKSample

Tags: wpf, xaml

In MSDN examples sometimes I see it is pointing to an SDK or library but there is no any link or pointer to the SDK to download. Is this a general style or I'm missing something ...

Just an example in following:

```
<Window x:Class="SDKSample.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="HierarchicalDataTemplate Sample"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:SDKSample">
  <DockPanel>
    <DockPanel.Resources>
      <src:ListLeagueList x:Key="MyList" />
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:League}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Divisions}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Division}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Teams}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Team}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <Menu Name="menu1"
          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
          Margin="10,10,10,10">
      <MenuItem Header="My Soccer Leagues"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}}" />
    </Menu>
    <TreeView>
      <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}}"
                    Header="My Soccer Leagues" />
    </TreeView>
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I'm looking at this xaml code on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx
It is all good but question I'm having is where can I find SDKSample class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlns:src="clr-namespace:SDKSample"` is a reference to the main project used for the documentation. You can see this because `Window1` uses the same namespace: `<Window x:Class="SDKSample.Window1"`

However, I don't see a way to download the whole documentation project. You will have to create the class `ListLeagueList` yourself. Fortunately there is an explanation of it:

> In the following example, `ListLeagueList` is a list of `League` objects.
>   Each `League` object has a `Name` and a collection of `Division` objects.
>   Each `Division` has a `Name` and a collection of `Team` objects, and each
>   `Team` object has a `Name`.

Answer (score 2):

This data can be found at the following path where all the samples and their backup files are hosted on GitHub.

[WPF-Samples->Data Binding->HierarchicalDataTemplate](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/fbee9021ef17407bc3aaa79ff282f25178a0c4af/Data%20Binding/HierarchicalDataTemplate/ListLeagueList.cs)

One can search for a particular filename within the repository to find its exact location and the same can either be downloaded or reproduced. The namespace given in the MSDN documentation may not be matching with the namespace used in the Samples repository but that can always be changed and the references need to be updated accordingly.

Comment: I would say this is the real answer and needs the green tick of justice! :)